# How to link to SO questions?

Tags: discussion

If I am asking a question on Stack Overflow and I want to refer to another SO question I can do this in two ways:

1. `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/...`
2. `http://stackoverflow.com/q/...`

First link is standard link, second is 'share' link. Main difference is that second link is 'my' link and when someone clicks this link it counts as my sharing. I can even get some badges this way.
So the question is which link is more appriopriate in this situation? Is it fair to add 'share'link in such case? Isn't 'share' link only for linking from outside of SO?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A couple of points to bear in mind:

1. The "share" link acts as a normal link when used within the Stack Exchange network. It doesn't count to the Announcer etc. badges unless the click is from outside the network.
2. The site automatically converts links copied from the url box into a human readable link. So:

   `https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276533/how-to-link-to-so-questions`

   becomes:

   [How to link to SO questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276533/how-to-link-to-so-questions)

   without you having to do anything.

So within the network the "long form" is preferable.

Answer (score 1):

I usually prefer to to follow the *`share link`* first (copy into browser URL), and link the (full link) result in my questions or answers here or on SO main site.